# "ItemizedOverlay" cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, installation

I am trying to create a [Android MapView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

In Part 2 of the article while implementing `ItemizedOverlay`, Eclipse is unable to pick it up from build path.

I am not sure about what part of SDK am missing.

Comment: Yep, solved the issue for me too. You should submit your findings as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not done this myself, but after a bit of digging, it seems the MapView is not a part of standard android.

I found [this](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html) on how to get it into your project, up and running.

Answer (score 0):

There was one another problem like

`The type ItemizedOverlay cannot be a superinterface of HelloItemizedOverlay; a superinterface must be an interface`

misleading line on [Android MapView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) which says

> Create a new Java class named HelloItemizedOverlay that implements
>   ItemizedOverlay.

But ideally it should be

> Create a new Java class named HelloItemizedOverlay that extends
>   ItemizedOverlay.